Sankey diagram gradient in Kibana with Vega
Anyone having an idea on how to create Sankey diagrams that the edges has gradient color from left rect's color to right rect's color?
This is sample Sankey diagram in Kibana:

And this is my code:
https://gist.github.com/s1031432/fdaf4bdbed15f1f1179317dbb93c985d
(I'm sorry that the code is so long)
{ 
 $schema: https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json
  data: [
    {
    // query ES based on the currently selected time range and filter string
    name: rawData
    url: {
        %context%: true
        %timefield%: timestamp
        index: kibana_sample_data_logs
        body: {
        size: 0
        aggs: {
            table: {
            composite: {
                size: 10000
                sources: [
                {
                    stk1: {
                    terms: {field: "machine.os.keyword"}
                    }
                }
                {
                    stk2: {
                    terms: {field: "geo.dest"}
                    }
                }
                ]
            }
            }
        }
        }
    }
    // From the result, take just the data we are interested in
    format: {property: "aggregations.table.buckets"}
    // Convert key.stk1 -> stk1 for simpler access below
    transform: [
        {type: "formula", expr: "datum.key.stk1", as: "stk1"}
        {type: "formula", expr: "datum.key.stk2", as: "stk2"}
        {type: "formula", expr: "datum.doc_count", as: "size"}
    ]
    }
    {
    name: nodes
    source: rawData
    transform: [
        // when a country is selected, filter out unrelated data
        {
        type: filter
        expr: !groupSelector || groupSelector.stk1 == datum.stk1 || groupSelector.stk2 == datum.stk2
        }
        // Set new key for later lookups - identifies each node
        {type: "formula", expr: "datum.stk1+datum.stk2", as: "key"}
        // instead of each table row, create two new rows,
        // one for the source (stack=stk1) and one for destination node (stack=stk2).
        // The country code stored in stk1 and stk2 fields is placed into grpId field.
        {
        type: fold
        fields: ["stk1", "stk2"]
        as: ["stack", "grpId"]
        }
        // Create a sortkey, different for stk1 and stk2 stacks.
        {
        type: formula
        expr: datum.stack == 'stk1' ? datum.stk1+datum.stk2 : datum.stk2+datum.stk1
        as: sortField
        }
        // Calculate y0 and y1 positions for stacking nodes one on top of the other,
        // independently for each stack, and ensuring they are in the proper order,
        // alphabetical from the top (reversed on the y axis)
        {
        type: stack
        groupby: ["stack"]
        sort: {field: "sortField", order: "descending"}
        field: size
        }
        // calculate vertical center point for each node, used to draw edges
        {type: "formula", expr: "(datum.y0+datum.y1)/2", as: "yc"}
    ]
    }
    {
    name: groups
    source: nodes
    transform: [
        // combine all nodes into country groups, summing up the doc counts
        {
        type: aggregate
        groupby: ["stack", "grpId"]
        fields: ["size"]
        ops: ["sum"]
        as: ["total"]
        }
        // re-calculate the stacking y0,y1 values
        {
        type: stack
        groupby: ["stack"]
        sort: {field: "grpId", order: "descending"}
        field: total
        }
        // project y0 and y1 values to screen coordinates
        // doing it once here instead of doing it several times in marks
        {type: "formula", expr: "scale('y', datum.y0)", as: "scaledY0"}
        {type: "formula", expr: "scale('y', datum.y1)", as: "scaledY1"}
        // boolean flag if the label should be on the right of the stack
        {type: "formula", expr: "datum.stack == 'stk1'", as: "rightLabel"}
        // Calculate traffic percentage for this country using "y" scale
        // domain upper bound, which represents the total traffic
        {
        type: formula
        expr: datum.total/domain('y')[1]
        as: percentage
        }
    ]
    }
    {
    name: dgroups
    source: nodes
    transform: [
        // combine all nodes into country groups, summing up the doc counts
        {
        type: aggregate
        groupby: ["stack", "grpId"]
        fields: ["size"]
        ops: ["sum"]
        as: ["total"]
        }
        // re-calculate the stacking y0,y1 values
        {
        type: stack
        groupby: ["stack"]
        sort: {field: "grpId", order: "descending"}
        field: total
        }
        // project y0 and y1 values to screen coordinates
        // doing it once here instead of doing it several times in marks
        {type: "formula", expr: "scale('y', datum.y0)", as: "scaledY0"}
        {type: "formula", expr: "scale('y', datum.y1)", as: "scaledY1"}
        // boolean flag if the label should be on the right of the stack
        {type: "formula", expr: "datum.stack == 'stk2'", as: "rightLabel"}
        // Calculate traffic percentage for this country using "y" scale
        // domain upper bound, which represents the total traffic
        {
        type: formula
        expr: datum.total/domain('y')[1]
        as: percentage
        }
    ]
    }
    {
    // This is a temp lookup table with all the 'stk2' stack nodes
    name: destinationNodes
    source: nodes
    transform: [
        {type: "filter", expr: "datum.stack == 'stk2'"}
    ]
    }
    {
    name: edges
    source: nodes
    transform: [
        // we only want nodes from the left stack
        {type: "filter", expr: "datum.stack == 'stk1'"}
        // find corresponding node from the right stack, keep it as "target"
        {
        type: lookup
        from: destinationNodes
        key: key
        fields: ["key"]
        as: ["target"]
        }
        // calculate SVG link path between stk1 and stk2 stacks for the node pair
        {
        type: linkpath
        orient: horizontal
        shape: diagonal
        sourceY: {expr: "scale('y', datum.yc)"}
        sourceX: {expr: "scale('x', 'stk1') + bandwidth('x')"}
        targetY: {expr: "scale('y', datum.target.yc)"}
        targetX: {expr: "scale('x', 'stk2')"}
        }
        // A little trick to calculate the thickness of the line.
        // The value needs to be the same as the hight of the node, but scaling
        // size to screen's height gives inversed value because screen's Y
        // coordinate goes from the top to the bottom, whereas the graph's Y=0
        // is at the bottom. So subtracting scaled doc count from screen height
        // (which is the "lower" bound of the "y" scale) gives us the right value
        {
        type: formula
        expr: range('y')[0]-scale('y', datum.size)
        as: strokeWidth
        }
        // Tooltip needs individual link's percentage of all traffic
        {
        type: formula
        expr: datum.size/domain('y')[1]
        as: percentage
        }
    ]
    }
  ]
  scales: [
    {
    // calculates horizontal stack positioning
    name: x
    type: band
    range: width
    domain: ["stk1", "stk2"]
    paddingOuter: 0
    paddingInner: 0.96
    }
    {
    // this scale goes up as high as the highest y1 value of all nodes
    name: y
    type: linear
    range: height
    domain: {data: "nodes", field: "y1"}
    }
    {
    // use rawData to ensure the colors stay the same when clicking.
    name: color
    type: ordinal
    range: category
    domain: {data: "rawData", field: "stk1"}
    }
    {
    // use rawData to ensure the colors stay the same when clicking.
    name: dcolor
    type: ordinal
    range: category
    domain: {data: "rawData", field: "stk2"}
    }
    {
    // this scale is used to map internal ids (stk1, stk2) to stack names
    name: stackNames
    type: ordinal
    range: ["Source", "Destination"]
    domain: ["stk1", "stk2"]
    }
  ]
  axes: [
    {
    // x axis should use custom label formatting to print proper stack names
    orient: bottom
    scale: x
    encode: {
        labels: {
        update: {
            text: {scale: "stackNames", field: "value"}
        }
        }
    }
    }
    {orient: "left", scale: "y"}
  ]
  marks: [
    {
    // draw the connecting line between stacks
    type: path
    name: edgeMark
    from: {data: "edges"}
    // this prevents some autosizing issues with large strokeWidth for paths
    clip: true
    encode: {
        update: {
        // By default use color of the left node, except when showing traffic
        // from just one country, in which case use destination color.
        stroke: [
            {
            test: groupSelector && groupSelector.stack=='stk1'
            scale: color
            field: stk2
            }
            {scale: "color", field: "stk1"}
        ]
        strokeWidth: {field: "strokeWidth"}
        path: {field: "path"}
        // when showing all traffic, and hovering over a country,
        // highlight the traffic from that country.
        strokeOpacity: {
            signal: !groupSelector && (groupHover.stk1 == datum.stk1 || groupHover.stk2 == datum.stk2) ? 0.9 : 0.3
        }
        // Ensure that the hover-selected edges show on top
        zindex: {
            signal: !groupSelector && (groupHover.stk1 == datum.stk1 || groupHover.stk2 == datum.stk2) ? 1 : 0
        }
        // format tooltip string
        tooltip: {
            signal: datum.stk1 + ' → ' + datum.stk2 + ' ' + format(datum.size, ',.0f') + '   (' + format(datum.percentage, '.1%') + ')'
        }
        }
        // Simple mouseover highlighting of a single line
        hover: {
        strokeOpacity: {value: 1}
        }
    }
    }
    {
    type: rect
    name: dgroupMark
    from: {data: "dgroups"}
    encode: {
        enter: {
        fill: {scale: "dcolor", field: "grpId"}
        stroke: {value: "#888"}
        strokeWidth: {value: 0.5}
        width: {scale: "x", band: 1}
        }
        update: {
        x: {scale: "x", field: "stack"}
        y: {field: "scaledY0"}
        y2: {field: "scaledY1"}
        fillOpacity: {value: 0.6}
        tooltip: {
            signal: datum.grpId + '   ' + format(datum.total, ',.0f') + '   (' + format(datum.percentage, '.1%') + ')'
        }
        }
        hover: {
        fillOpacity: {value: 1}
        }
    }
    }
    {
    // draw stack groups (countries)
    type: rect
    name: groupMark
    from: {data: "groups"}
    encode: {
        enter: {
        fill: {scale: "color", field: "grpId"}
        width: {scale: "x", band: 1}
        }
        update: {
        x: {scale: "x", field: "stack"}
        y: {field: "scaledY0"}
        y2: {field: "scaledY1"}
        fillOpacity: {value: 0.6}
        tooltip: {
            signal: datum.grpId + '   ' + format(datum.total, ',.0f') + '   (' + format(datum.percentage, '.1%') + ')'
        }
        }
        hover: {
        fillOpacity: {value: 1}
        }
    }
    }
    {
    // draw country code labels on the inner side of the stack
    type: text
    from: {data: "groups"}
    // don't process events for the labels - otherwise line mouseover is unclean
    interactive: false
    encode: {
        update: {
        // depending on which stack it is, position x with some padding
        x: {
            signal: scale('x', datum.stack) + (datum.rightLabel ? bandwidth('x') + 8 : -8)
        }
        // middle of the group
        yc: {signal: "(datum.scaledY0 + datum.scaledY1)/2"}
        align: {signal: "datum.rightLabel ? 'left' : 'right'"}
        baseline: {value: "middle"}
        fontWeight: {value: "bold"}
        // only show text label if the group's height is large enough
        text: {signal: "abs(datum.scaledY0-datum.scaledY1) > 13 ? datum.grpId : ''"}
        }
    }
    }
    {
    // Create a "show all" button. Shown only when a country is selected.
    type: group
    data: [
        // We need to make the button show only when groupSelector signal is true.
        // Each mark is drawn as many times as there are elements in the backing data.
        // Which means that if values list is empty, it will not be drawn.
        // Here I create a data source with one empty object, and filter that list
        // based on the signal value. This can only be done in a group.
        {
        name: dataForShowAll
        values: [{}]
        transform: [{type: "filter", expr: "groupSelector"}]
        }
    ]
    // Set button size and positioning
    encode: {
        enter: {
        xc: {signal: "width/2"}
        y: {value: 30}
        width: {value: 80}
        height: {value: 30}
        }
    }
    marks: [
        {
        // This group is shown as a button with rounded corners.
        type: group
        // mark name allows signal capturing
        name: groupReset
        // Only shows button if dataForShowAll has values.
        from: {data: "dataForShowAll"}
        encode: {
            enter: {
            cornerRadius: {value: 6}
            fill: {value: "#F5F7FA"}
            stroke: {value: "#c1c1c1"}
            strokeWidth: {value: 2}
            // use parent group's size
            height: {
                field: {group: "height"}
            }
            width: {
                field: {group: "width"}
            }
            }
            update: {
            // groups are transparent by default
            opacity: {value: 1}
            }
            hover: {
            opacity: {value: 0.7}
            }
        }
        marks: [
            {
            type: text
            // if true, it will prevent clicking on the button when over text.
            interactive: false
            encode: {
                enter: {
                // center text in the paren group
                xc: {
                    field: {group: "width"}
                    mult: 0.5
                }
                yc: {
                    field: {group: "height"}
                    mult: 0.5
                    offset: 2
                }
                align: {value: "center"}
                baseline: {value: "middle"}
                fontWeight: {value: "bold"}
                text: {value: "Show All"}
                }
            }
            }
        ]
        }
    ]
    }
  ]
  signals: [
    {
    // used to highlight traffic to/from the same country
    name: groupHover
    value: {}
    on: [
        {
        events: @groupMark:mouseover
        update: "{stk1:datum.stack=='stk1' && datum.grpId, stk2:datum.stack=='stk2' && datum.grpId}"
        }
        {events: "mouseout", update: "{}"}
    ]
    }
    {
    // used to highlight traffic to/from the same country
    name: dgroupHover
    value: {}
    on: [
        {
        events: @dgroupMark:mouseover
        update: "{stk2:datum.grpId=='stk2' && datum.grpId, stk1:datum.grpId=='stk1' && datum.stack}"
        }
        {events: "mouseout", update: "{}"}
    ]
    }
    // used to filter only the data related to the selected country
    {
    name: groupSelector
    value: false
    on: [
        {
        // Clicking groupMark sets this signal to the filter values
        events: @groupMark:click!
        update: "{stack:datum.stack, stk1:datum.stack=='stk1' && datum.grpId, stk2:datum.stack=='stk2' && datum.grpId}"
        }
        {
        // Clicking "show all" button, or double-clicking anywhere resets it
        events: [
            {type: "click", markname: "groupReset"}
            {type: "dblclick"}
        ]
        update: "false"
        }
    ]
    }
  ]
}

For example:
I want the color of edge from ios(left) to CN(right) is green to purple rather than the edge is only green.
Sample from reddit
The edge connect between left and right color is gradient.

Thank you so much.

Does this answer your question? Sankey Diagram (Alluvial Diagram) in Vega-lite

@davidebacci Thank you, I've already read the article over there before I post this question but the problem seems to be the Javascript version and there is no mention of how to do the edge connect left rect and right rect with gradient color from left rect color to right rect color in Vega.

Please refer to this similar question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78374021/make-a-gradient-edge-from-two-rect-in-sankey-diagram-with-vega
