Make a gradient edge from two rect in Sankey diagram with Vega
I want to make a gradient edge which color is from left rect color to right rect color.
I tried it and read Vega documentation for a long time but still couldn't get the effect I wanted...
My sample code on Vega editor

I only made gradients of specific colors (blue to red).
How should I modify my code so that the edge connecting two rects will change according to the color of the rects?
Thank you so much.

Building on @APB Reports answer. Before at full opacity (colours don't quite match the stacks):

After changing the stops:

{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "height": 700,
  "width": 700,
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "rawData",
      "values": {
        "aggregations": {
          "table": {
            "buckets": [
              {"key": {"stk1": "aa", "stk2": "dd"}, "doc_count": 7},
              {"key": {"stk1": "bb", "stk2": "cc"}, "doc_count": 2},
              {"key": {"stk1": "cc", "stk2": "aa"}, "doc_count": 8},
              {"key": {"stk1": "dd", "stk2": "bb"}, "doc_count": 11}
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "format": {"property": "aggregations.table.buckets"},
      "transform": [
        {"type": "formula", "expr": "datum.key.stk1", "as": "stk1"},
        {"type": "formula", "expr": "datum.key.stk2", "as": "stk2"},
        {"type": "formula", "expr": "datum.doc_count", "as": "size"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "nodes",
      "source": "rawData",
      "transform": [
        {"type": "formula", "expr": "datum.stk1+datum.stk2", "as": "key"},
        {"type": "fold", "fields": ["stk1", "stk2"], "as": ["stack", "grpId"]},
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "datum.stack == 'stk1' ? datum.stk1+datum.stk2 : datum.stk2+datum.stk1",
          "as": "sortField"
        },
        {
          "type": "stack",
          "groupby": ["stack"],
          "sort": {"field": "sortField", "order": "descending"},
          "field": "size"
        },
        {"type": "formula", "expr": "(datum.y0+datum.y1)/2", "as": "yc"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "groups",
      "source": "nodes",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "aggregate",
          "groupby": ["stack", "grpId"],
          "fields": ["size"],
          "ops": ["sum"],
          "as": ["total"]
        },
        {
          "type": "stack",
          "groupby": ["stack"],
          "sort": {"field": "grpId", "order": "descending"},
          "field": "total"
        },
        {"type": "formula", "expr": "scale('y', datum.y0)", "as": "scaledY0"},
        {"type": "formula", "expr": "scale('y', datum.y1)", "as": "scaledY1"},
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "datum.stack == 'stk1'",
          "as": "rightLabel"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "datum.total/domain('y')[1]",
          "as": "percentage"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "destinationNodes",
      "source": "nodes",
      "transform": [{"type": "filter", "expr": "datum.stack == 'stk2'"}]
    },
    {
      "name": "edges",
      "source": "nodes",
      "transform": [
        {"type": "filter", "expr": "datum.stack == 'stk1'"},
        {
          "type": "lookup",
          "from": "destinationNodes",
          "key": "key",
          "fields": ["key"],
          "as": ["target"]
        },
        {
          "type": "linkpath",
          "orient": "horizontal",
          "shape": "diagonal",
          "sourceY": {"expr": "scale('y', datum.yc)"},
          "sourceX": {"expr": "scale('x', 'stk1') + bandwidth('x')"},
          "targetY": {"expr": "scale('y', datum.target.yc)"},
          "targetX": {"expr": "scale('x', 'stk2')"}
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "range('y')[0]-scale('y', datum.size)",
          "as": "strokeWidth"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "datum.size/domain('y')[1]",
          "as": "percentage"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "x",
      "type": "band",
      "range": "width",
      "domain": ["stk1", "stk2"],
      "paddingOuter": 0,
      "paddingInner": 0.95
    },
    {
      "name": "y",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": "height",
      "domain": {"data": "nodes", "field": "y1"}
    },
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "range": ["#1f77b4", "#ff7f0e", "#2ca02c", "#BC3FDC"],
      "domain": ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"], 
    },
    {
      "name": "stackNames",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "range": ["Source", "Destination"],
      "domain": ["stk1", "stk2"]
    }
  ],
  "axes": [
    {
      "orient": "bottom",
      "scale": "x",
      "encode": {
        "labels": {
          "update": {"text": {"scale": "stackNames", "field": "value"}}
        }
      }
    },
    {"orient": "left", "scale": "y"}
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data": "nodes"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "stroke": {"value": "#000"},
          "strokeWidth": {"value": 1},
          "width": {"scale": "x", "band": 1},
          "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "stack"},
          "y": {"field": "y0", "scale": "y"},
          "y2": {"field": "y1", "scale": "y"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "path",
      "name": "edgeMark",
      "from": {"data": "edges"},
      "clip": true,
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "stroke": [
            {
              "signal": "{'gradient': 'linear','stops': [{'offset': 0.3, 'color': scale('color', datum.stk1)},{'offset': 0.7, 'color': scale('color', datum.target.stk2)}]}"
            }
          ],
          "strokeWidth": {"field": "strokeWidth"},
          "path": {"field": "path"},
          "strokeOpacity": {"signal": "1"},
          "zindex": {"signal": "0"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "rect",
      "name": "groupMark",
      "from": {"data": "groups"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "grpId"},
          "width": {"scale": "x", "band": 1}
        },
        "update": {
          "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "stack"},
          "y": {"field": "scaledY0"},
          "y2": {"field": "scaledY1"},
          "fillOpacity": {"value": 1}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}


Good idea with the stops @davidebacci. I always trust you to take it to the next level :)

I added a range to your color scale and a signal to your path stroke gradient.

{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "height": 500,
  "width": 500,
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "rawData",
      "values": {
        "aggregations": {
          "table": {
            "buckets": [
              {"key": {"stk1": "aa", "stk2": "dd"}, "doc_count": 7},
              {"key": {"stk1": "bb", "stk2": "cc"}, "doc_count": 2},
              {"key": {"stk1": "cc", "stk2": "aa"}, "doc_count": 8},
              {"key": {"stk1": "dd", "stk2": "bb"}, "doc_count": 11}
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "format": {"property": "aggregations.table.buckets"},
      "transform": [
        {"type": "formula", "expr": "datum.key.stk1", "as": "stk1"},
        {"type": "formula", "expr": "datum.key.stk2", "as": "stk2"},
        {"type": "formula", "expr": "datum.doc_count", "as": "size"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "nodes",
      "source": "rawData",
      "transform": [
        {"type": "formula", "expr": "datum.stk1+datum.stk2", "as": "key"},
        {"type": "fold", "fields": ["stk1", "stk2"], "as": ["stack", "grpId"]},
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "datum.stack == 'stk1' ? datum.stk1+datum.stk2 : datum.stk2+datum.stk1",
          "as": "sortField"
        },
        {
          "type": "stack",
          "groupby": ["stack"],
          "sort": {"field": "sortField", "order": "descending"},
          "field": "size"
        },
        {"type": "formula", "expr": "(datum.y0+datum.y1)/2", "as": "yc"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "groups",
      "source": "nodes",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "aggregate",
          "groupby": ["stack", "grpId"],
          "fields": ["size"],
          "ops": ["sum"],
          "as": ["total"]
        },
        {
          "type": "stack",
          "groupby": ["stack"],
          "sort": {"field": "grpId", "order": "descending"},
          "field": "total"
        },
        {"type": "formula", "expr": "scale('y', datum.y0)", "as": "scaledY0"},
        {"type": "formula", "expr": "scale('y', datum.y1)", "as": "scaledY1"},
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "datum.stack == 'stk1'",
          "as": "rightLabel"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "datum.total/domain('y')[1]",
          "as": "percentage"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "destinationNodes",
      "source": "nodes",
      "transform": [{"type": "filter", "expr": "datum.stack == 'stk2'"}]
    },
    {
      "name": "edges",
      "source": "nodes",
      "transform": [
        {"type": "filter", "expr": "datum.stack == 'stk1'"},
        {
          "type": "lookup",
          "from": "destinationNodes",
          "key": "key",
          "fields": ["key"],
          "as": ["target"]
        },
        {
          "type": "linkpath",
          "orient": "horizontal",
          "shape": "diagonal",
          "sourceY": {"expr": "scale('y', datum.yc)"},
          "sourceX": {"expr": "scale('x', 'stk1') + bandwidth('x')"},
          "targetY": {"expr": "scale('y', datum.target.yc)"},
          "targetX": {"expr": "scale('x', 'stk2')"}
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "range('y')[0]-scale('y', datum.size)",
          "as": "strokeWidth"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "datum.size/domain('y')[1]",
          "as": "percentage"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "x",
      "type": "band",
      "range": "width",
      "domain": ["stk1", "stk2"],
      "paddingOuter": 0,
      "paddingInner": 0.95
    },
    {
      "name": "y",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": "height",
      "domain": {"data": "nodes", "field": "y1"}
    },
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "range": ["#1f77b4", "#ff7f0e", "#2ca02c", "#BC3FDC"],
      "domain": ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"]
    },
    {
      "name": "stackNames",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "range": ["Source", "Destination"],
      "domain": ["stk1", "stk2"]
    }
  ],
  "axes": [
    {
      "orient": "bottom",
      "scale": "x",
      "encode": {
        "labels": {
          "update": {"text": {"scale": "stackNames", "field": "value"}}
        }
      }
    },
    {"orient": "left", "scale": "y"}
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data": "nodes"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "stroke": {"value": "#000"},
          "strokeWidth": {"value": 0},
          "width": {"scale": "x", "band": 1},
          "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "stack"},
          "y": {"field": "y0", "scale": "y"},
          "y2": {"field": "y1", "scale": "y"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "path",
      "name": "edgeMark",
      "from": {"data": "edges"},
      "clip": true,
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "stroke": [
            {
              "signal": "{'gradient': 'linear','stops': [{'offset': 0.2, 'color': scale('color', datum.stk1)},{'offset': 0.8, 'color': scale('color', datum.target.stk2)}]}"
            }
          ],
          "strokeWidth": {"field": "strokeWidth"},
          "path": {"field": "path"},
          "strokeOpacity": {"value": 0.7},
          "zindex": {"signal": "0"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "rect",
      "name": "groupMark",
      "from": {"data": "groups"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "grpId"},
          "width": {"scale": "x", "band": 1}
        },
        "update": {
          "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "stack"},
          "y": {"field": "scaledY0"},
          "y2": {"field": "scaledY1"},
          "fillOpacity": {"value": 1}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}


Nice. Should the colours at the end of the gradient match the stacks? They seem to be slightly off.

@davidebacci strokeOpacity (line 186) and fillOpacity (line 204) should ideally be the same. Spec updated

Thanks @APB but I still see slightly different colours. I'm just not sure why and think something weird is happening with the interpolation so may be a Vega bug. If you change the opacity of both to 1, you can see they don't quite match. For instance, the top left stack (#1f77b4), the link connecting it only gets to #4868bf which is close but not the actual colour the gradient should end on. I suspect a bug but maybe you have other ideas?

Actually, I see the issue. I'll add answer with full opacity so you can see what I mean. You just need to change the stops.
